# Scrollbar is not appearing even though overflow is set to "auto" and white-space is set to "pre"

Tags: css

I've been staring at this for quite a while and I'm *sure* it's something obvious, but I need another set of eyes.

I'm using Google Prettify to syntax highlight code blocks on my Tumblr blog.  Everything is working great except I don't want the code to wrap unless it is truly an EOL.  Instead, a scrollbar should appear when the text is too wide for the containing block.

Here's an example: http://accidentalhacker.com/post/15521210350/sticky-notes-with-css3

If I inspect the `<pre>` element in Chrome, `overflow` is properly set to `auto` and `white-space` is set to `pre`, so I have no idea why the text is still wrapping.

Comment: I'm not quite sure where I see what you're talking about in the example. Can you post some sample code?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The wrapping is caused by the `word-wrap: break-word` setting on the enclosing `div` element. For some reason, Chrome does not show this property as inherited when you inspect the `pre` element, but it still affects the rendering.

If the setting is needed for the `div` for some reason, override it by setting `word-wrap: normal` for the `pre` element.

Comment: Awesome! That's what I missed, `word-wrap`!  Looks like the default style sheet for my theme was setting that improperly (for what I needed).